# SQLAlchemy relationship to any class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to build a SQLAlchemy relationship that will accept any instance that inherits from the same `Base`? Ideally, it maintains one foreign key for the instance's ID and a second foreign key for the instance's type.

As an example, this `Variable` class has a relationship `applies_to` between itself and the `Car` class.

```
# some overhead, for completeness
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
session = Session(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

# defining my classes
class Variable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'variables'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(Integer)

    applies_to_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cars.id'))
    applies_to = relationship('Car')

class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Truck(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trucks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

With it, I can make a `Car` and a `Variable` for that car and commit to the database.

```
car = Car()
var1 = Variable(name="speed", value=50, applies_to=car)
session.add(car)
session.add(var1)
session.commit()
```

But I cannot do a similar thing with `Truck` and `Variable`.

```
truck = Truck()
var2 = Variable(name="speed", value=50, applies_to=truck)
session.add(truck)
session.add(var2)
session.commit()

AssertionError: Attribute 'applies_to' on class '<class '__main__.Variable'>' doesn't handle objects of type '<class '__main__.Truck'>'
```

I would like to edit the `Variable` class to support `Truck` and any other classes that inherit from `Base` through the `applies_to` relationship.

EDIT: Similar to [sqlalchemy generic foreign key (like in django ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703239), but that solution requires all classes to inherit from the `HasAddresses` mixin and handles a backref via `addresses` on those classes. Is there a solution that only edits the `Variable` class and doesn't maintain a backref to the other classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlalchemy generic foreign key (like in django ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703239/sqlalchemy-generic-foreign-key-like-in-django-orm)

Comment: Also since a truck is a car, you could have a look at the inheritance patterns, but "and any other classes" means you're after the generic association, one way or another -- though it's considered an anti pattern by many.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, that solution requires all classes to inherit from `HasAddresses`. Is it possible to achieve a similar outcome without needing to edit the other classes? I don't need a backref